# Why variables and constants are operations in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Intuitively, I expected an operation to be something that takes an input and modifies it (add, substract, divide, square root...). In fact, that's the definition of operation I found on the Internet. Then, **why variables and constants are also operations in TensorFlow?**

Comment: Did the answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow generalizes your definition of operation as *something that takes zero or more inputs and produces zero or more outputs*. Concretely, a [TensorFlow Operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) is defined as:

> An Operation is a node in a TensorFlow Graph that takes zero or more Tensor objects as input, and produces zero or more Tensor objects as output.

Therefore:

- A constant is an operation without inputs that produces a single `Tensor` as output.
- A variable is a special (stateful) operation that takes one `Tensor` (initial value) as input and produces another `Tensor` as output.